# How to run Matlab code on an Android device?

Tags: android, matlab, matlab-deployment

I would like to run Matlab code on an Android device. There is the JAVA Builder in Matlab, which can create Java classes from the M-Files. But it requires a MatlabRunTime to be installed on the target machine. I use Matlab on Windows, so the JAVA Builder creates a MatlabRunTime as *.

**Is there a way to run M-Files on an Android Smartphone?**

Comment: I think you'd better try to run matlab remotely on a server...

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to use any of the deployment products (including MATLAB Compiler and MATLAB Builder for Java) to run MATLAB code on Android. The deployed components you get from any of those products depend on the MATLAB Compiler Runtime, which has a much larger footprint than an Android device could handle.

You could consider either

1. Writing an app that connects, as @Oli suggested, to MATLAB code (or deployed MATLAB code) running somewhere on a server
2. Using MATLAB Coder, which can convert a subset of the MATLAB language into C code that could be integrated into your app.

Answer (score 2):

Try out an app called [Addi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addi&hl=en).  It does a lot and is getting better.

Comment: Hi corbin, interesting hint, but you might've wanted to mention that Addi is your own product. :) Btw., why did you develop something new that appears to be only a bit like Matlab when there is already [Octave for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octave&hl=en) which is largely Matlab compatible, at least regarding the numeric core functionality?

Comment: I actually developed Addi before Octave for Android.