# How to make an Android app with Matlab code?

Tags: android, matlab

I've made an algorithm in Matlab for hiding images into images, and now I want to make an Android app that uses this algorithm.

Generating C++ code using Matlab code is a bit difficult for me, as I do not have enough knowledge of C++. Using the Matlab builder I generated a Java class of my Matlab algorithm, but it is having errors which I'm not able to sort out. Is there any direct way to do it? Also these generated codes, i.e. Java class or C++ code, require Matlab Compiler Runtime to be installed on machine having no Matlab compiler, and they are very memory hungry for use in mobile devices. I have found "Matlab Mobile" while searching for the solutions, but it is costly :(

**How can I add ( turn a ) Matlab code to Android application ?** If someone knows a better solution, please do let me know :)

Comment: Did you take a look at this yet ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033999/how-to-run-matlab-code-on-android-device

Comment: @JamesC i've already seen it :)
i've already mentioned it that generating a java class using matlab builder ja requires a mcr to be installed on a computer having no matlab compiler, and generating c++ code using matlab coder is a bit difficult for me as i've a very little knowledge of c++ :(
and there are alot of things to be specified in matlab coder.. e.g. in matlab i don't have to define the type of variable, but to gemerate c++ code, it requires every variable type to be defined, and also there are other things too in it which i'm finding difficult for me :(

Comment: Ok, it looks like I didn't understand your question too well, because I thought the answer is already at that other question. Can you tell what is missing in the answers there, so I ( we ) can help you out better ?

Comment: @JamesC i'm asking for is there any other solution for doing it?

Comment: i was searhing for the solutions and got another solution, convert ur matlab code to python and then use it in android, but having an in depth search on the comments for those code converters, i found out that they've the same complication like c++ or something like that :(

Comment: do u've a solution like that mentioned above, that's easy and effective?
@JamesC

Comment: There are many options mentioned in that other question ( Addi, remote server ) and I think users there pretty much exhausted the list of current ( well known and proven to work ) possibilities. I can't add anything else to this unfortunately, but someone else may.