# vText Voice password does not load on Android

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

For my semester project I am trying to identify speaker on Android. For this purpose, I have been trying to integrate vText java library to Android Studio. You can find the page through this [link](http://www.basic-signalprocessing.com/downloadVText.htm). However, I got the .jar files which are mentioned in the web page and tried to do sample things for discovering the library and I got `java.lang.VerifyError`. Of course I searched for it but did not get anything handy.I tried to change JDK version but I could not make it,too. If anyone can help me for using this library in Android Studio properly.

Here is my code part relevant to this problem.

```
btnVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        btnVoice.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 + " seconds.");
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        stopRecording();
                        try {
                            vTText=new vTextClass();
                            vTText.dataAcq(1, filename);
                            System.out.println("Recording completed");
                        } catch (MWException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library uses matlab component runtime, which is not available on android. See [How to run Matlab code on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033999/how-to-run-matlab-code-on-an-android-device)

You can use other framework instead like [Recognito](https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito)

Comment: The Project Oxford library might also be of use https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/SpeakerRecognition

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses guys.But I also tried to use Recognito unfortunalety I could not find any jar and could not integrate it into android studio.Is it possible to share some helpful links which can help for Recognito?

Comment: You can just include all the sources into your codebase.

Comment: As you suggest,I tried to integrate Recognito again but still I could not get it.Can you guys help me to use Recognito in Android Studio?

Comment: Guys for now,I managed to integrate the project into Android Studio but unfortunaletly I got 'javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException'.Also tried to manage this,too but I could not import javax.sound.sampled to the project as wel.Please help guys.